# Using "hue" for a Seaborn visual: how to get legend in one graph?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a scatter plot in seaborn using seaborn.relplot, but am having trouble putting the legend all in one graph.

When I do this simple way, everything works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df2 = df[df.ln_amt_000s < 700]
sns.relplot(x='ln_amt_000s', y='hud_med_fm_inc', hue='outcome', size='outcome', legend='brief', ax=ax, data=df2)
```

The result is a scatter plot as desired, with the legend on the right hand side.

[image]

However, when I try to generate a matplotlib figure and axes objects ahead of time to specify the figure dimensions I run into problems:

```
a4_dims = (10, 10) # generating a matplotlib figure and axes objects ahead of time to specify figure dimensions
df2 = df[df.ln_amt_000s < 700]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = a4_dims)
sns.relplot(x='ln_amt_000s', y='hud_med_fm_inc', hue='outcome', size='outcome', legend='brief', ax=ax, data=df2)
```

The result is two graphs -- one that has the scatter plots as expected but missing the legend, and another one below it that is all blank except for the legend on the right hand side.
[image]

How do I fix this such? My desired result is one graph where I can specify the figure dimensions and have the legend at the bottom in two rows, below the x-axis (if that is too difficult, or not supported, then the default legend position to the right on the same graph would work too)? I know the problem lies with "ax=ax", and in the way I am specifying the dimensions as matplotlib figure, but I'd like to know specifically why this causes a problem so I can learn from this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `sns.relplot` is a "Figure-level interface for drawing relational plots onto a FacetGrid" (see the [API page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)). With a simple `sns.scatterplot` (the default type of plot used by `sns.relplot`), your code works (changed to use reproducible data):

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/iris.csv", index_col=0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
sns.scatterplot(x = 'Sepal.Length', y = 'Sepal.Width', 
            hue = 'Species', legend = 'brief',
            ax=ax, data = df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Further edits to legend

Seaborn's legends are a bit finicky. Some tweaks you may want to employ:

- Remove the default seaborn title, which is actually a legend entry, by getting and slicing the handles and labels
- Set a new title that is actually a title
- Move the location and make use of `bbox_to_anchor` to move outside the plot area (note that the `bbox` parameters need some tweaking depending on your plot size)
- Specify the number of columns

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
sns.scatterplot(x = 'Sepal.Length', y = 'Sepal.Width', 
            hue = 'Species', legend = 'brief',
            ax=ax, data = df)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], loc=8, 
          ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=[0.5,-.3,0,0])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Brendan! Your explanation was very insightful -- I learned so much from it, more than just for the sake of solving my one problem. Thank you!